# c# UWP Get VirtualKey from a string

Tags: c#, enums, uwp

How can I get a VirtualKey enum from a string? For example trying to get the enum for the letter "w" from the string "w".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse` is what you're after, examples:

- `var vk = (VirtualKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKey), "W");`
- `if (Enum.TryParse<VirtualKey>("W", out var vk)) WriteLine("Yay!");`

You can also perform a search ignoring case:

- `var vk = (VirtualKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKey), "w", true);`
- `if (Enum.TryParse<VirtualKey>("w", true, out var vk)) WriteLine("Yay!");`